# Revision Tracking & Source Control for Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, tools, visual-studio-2015, source-control, azure-sql-data-warehouse

What is a good approaching for tracking incremental changes to database tables, stored procedures, etc for Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

I am in the process of moving a large database over to Azure SQL Data Warehouse. The prior approach for change tracking was using a 'Database Project' in Visual Studio 2015. This allows easy source control integration with TFS or Git or whatever. When you want to publish, you just target the destination database and it generates a change script.

This functionality does not at all work for Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Visual Studio (and the latest SSDT) simply can't target SQL DW. This means the process of publishing is extremely tedious, entirely manual and extremely error prone.

Is there another comparable approach you are using for this type of project?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has started work on this and there is a [signup page](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR4-brmKy3TZOjoktwuHd7S1UODkwQ1lVMEw1NDBGRjNLRDNWOFlQRUpIRi4u) for a preview version. In the meantime you may want to look at DBUp and [FiveTran](https://fivetran.com/blog/azure-dwh-launch), although I haven't worked with either of these.

**Update**: As of Aug 2019, it is publicly available in preview.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-install-visual-studio

You'll want to vote for this thread:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/13313247--in-preview-database-project-from-visual-studio-t

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997938/azure-sql-data-warehouse-db-development-tools